# SSIS pacakge shows it ran successfully but eventually doesnt trigger the process

Tags: ssis

I have created a SSIS package and SQL job to run it. When I execute the package manually it works fine. I am logging information of the job processed which I can see however when I execute the job it shows it ran successfully in job history. I have set it to log an event on failure but don't find any events either. I am not sure what the problem is. The only difference is the while running it manually its using my windows account while running it via job is its using service account. Upon verification of data I can see that the process hasnt kicked off. Could somebody tell me what the problem could be

Comment: I know I have seen many an issue along these lines where it is a permissions issue for the service account somewhere along the line.  Try running VS locally as the service account and see what happens.  You should get more informative errors

Answer (score 0):

In every task in your package you will find the properties, FailPackageOnFailure and FailParentOnFailure.

If an task fails, and does not cause the package to fail due to either of these properties, then the job will show that it completed successfully even though the package errored and did not complete successfully.